# Distinct count across two tables - use outer join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to look for the count (distinct MEM_ID) across both Z_KSS and Z_KSS2.  If a MEM_ID appears in both Z_KSS and Z_KSS2, it should only be counted once.  Do I use Outer Join?  Do I need to specify an On condition?

```
Select count (distinct MEM_ID), sum(Amount)
      , 'KSS' Company
      FROM    temp_09.Z_KSS
       FULL OUTER JOIN temp_09.Z_KSS2
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'm just trying to query both tables at once for the same thing - count (distinct MEM_ID) across both tables.

Comment: Is the `MEM_ID` unique in both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you want `union all` :

```
SELECT count(distinct MEM_ID), sum(Amount), 'KSS' Company
FROM  ((SELECT MEM_ID, Amount
        FROM temp_09.Z_KSS
       ) UNION ALL
       (SELECT DISTINCT MEM_ID, Amount
        FROM temp_09.Z_KSS2
       )
      ) t;
```

Comment: Any particular advantage of Union All vs. Outer Join?

Comment: @ZJAY . . . If should produce the correct answer, even if `MEM_ID` is duplicated in either table.